# Fastest query for getting stock prices from yfinance python

Tags: python, yfinance

I am working on a flask web server that requires me to pull the current cryptocurrency prices dynamically every time a certain page is loaded. I am using the Yfinance library to get the price from the crypto-usd pair. to do this, i run this query for each cryptocurrency:

```
import yfinance as yf
bch_price = yf.Ticker("BCH-USD").info["regularMarketPrice"]
```

This works perfectly fine, however,it takes very long when querying for multiple pairs.
My question is: Is there a faster way to query JUST for the price object in yfinance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

query all tickers together --from docs

```
data = yf.download(  # or pdr.get_data_yahoo(...
        # tickers list or string as well
        tickers = "SPY AAPL MSFT",

        # use "period" instead of start/end
        # valid periods: 1d,5d,1mo,3mo,6mo,1y,2y,5y,10y,ytd,max
        # (optional, default is '1mo')
        period = "ytd",

        # fetch data by interval (including intraday if period < 60 days)
        # valid intervals: 1m,2m,5m,15m,30m,60m,90m,1h,1d,5d,1wk,1mo,3mo
        # (optional, default is '1d')
        interval = "1m",

        # group by ticker (to access via data['SPY'])
        # (optional, default is 'column')
        group_by = 'ticker',

        # adjust all OHLC automatically
        # (optional, default is False)
        auto_adjust = True,

        # download pre/post regular market hours data
        # (optional, default is False)
        prepost = True,

        # use threads for mass downloading? (True/False/Integer)
        # (optional, default is True)
        threads = True,

        # proxy URL scheme use use when downloading?
        # (optional, default is None)
        proxy = None
    )
```

https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/

Comment: you can also instiatiate multiple tickers at once with tickers object tickers = yf.Tickers('msft aapl goog')